# Как решить ошибку subquery must return only one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

В результате sql запроса хочу получить объект с полем test которое будет массивом и будет содержать в себе различные объекты.

```
    SELECT  sensor_instances.*,
    row_to_json((SELECT d
      FROM  (SELECT groups.*) d
    )) AS group,
    row_to_json((SELECT a
      FROM (SELECT addresses.*) a
    )) AS currentAddress,
    ARRAY(
      SELECT sensor_parameters.*
      FROM sensor_parameters
      WHERE sensor_parameters.sensortype IN (sensor_instances.sensortype)
    ) AS test
FROM sensor_instances
LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id = sensor_instances.groupid 
LEFT JOIN addresses ON sensor_instances.addressid = addresses.id
WHERE sensor_instances.id IN (89)
```

Но в результате запрос возвращает ошибку

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 8:   ARRAY(
```

Может кто то знает как получить в поле test массив с перечнем объектов?

Ожидаемый результат

```
{
    currentaddress: {},
    group: {},
    test: [{},{}]
}
```

Пример данных из таблицы sensor_parameters
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что значит "массив содержит в себе различые объекты" ? Массив это по сути набор однотипных объектов ( только числа, только строки, etc)

Comment: необходима записать результат подзапроса в масив, т.е test:[{}, {}]

Comment: добавьте ожидаемый результат, а в идеале вообще DDL таблиц + тестовые данные

Comment: Обновил описание

Comment: @AlexVexler, опять же, для *твоих данных* какой **именно** вывод ты ожидаешь? и в каком формате? ЗЫ: всю информацию лучше приводить в виде текста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  sensor_instances.*,
    row_to_json((SELECT d
      FROM  (SELECT groups.*) d
    )) AS group,
    row_to_json((SELECT a
      FROM (SELECT addresses.*) a
    )) AS currentAddress,
    ARRAY(
      SELECT row_to_json(t)
      FROM(
        SELECT sensor_parameters.*
        FROM sensor_parameters
        WHERE sensor_parameters.sensortype IN (sensor_instances.sensortype)) t
    ) AS test
FROM sensor_instances
LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id = sensor_instances.groupid 
LEFT JOIN addresses ON sensor_instances.addressid = addresses.id
WHERE sensor_instances.id IN (89)
```